# Isomorphism between $\bigwedge^2\mathbb R^3$ and the dual of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$

Tags: lie-algebras, exterior-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I need to show that the map $L:\bigwedge^2\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathfrak{so}(3)^*$ defined by $L(x\wedge y)\Omega=\langle \Omega x,y\rangle$ for $\Omega\in \mathfrak{so}(3)$ is an isomorphism. This map is clearly skewsymmetric, but I cannot show that it is injective. Clearly, if  $L(x_1\wedge x_2)=L(y_1\wedge y_2)$, then we have $\langle \Omega(x_1-y_1),(x_2-y_2)\rangle=0$, no-degeneracy of the inner product should to the trick, but I cannot justify this explicitly.

Comment: What is your action of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ on $\mathbb R^n$?  Or should $n=3$?

Comment: @Aaron yes, n=3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are identifying $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and the action is given by the Lie bracket you have:$$L(e_i \wedge e_j)(e_k)=\langle[e_k,e_i],e_j\rangle=\langle[e_i,e_j],e_k\rangle$$
for $i,j,k\in \{1,2,3\}$.  Then \begin{eqnarray*}
L(e_1\wedge e_2)&=&e_3^*,\\
L(e_2\wedge e_3)&=&e_1^*,\\
L(e_3\wedge e_1)&=&e_2^*.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus you have an isomorphism of vector spaces, as your map takes one basis to another.

Comment: In hindsight the action was probably supposed to be induced from the standard representation of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$.  However, this action may be identified with the one I used, so the answer is the same.